# Convert all images into clickable A tags with img inside

Tags: php, html

I have a block of html with a lot of `<img src="..."/>` inside of it.

Now I'm looking for a way to make this:

`<img src="lol.jpg"/>` into:

```
<a href="lol.jpg" class="image_inside_text" target="_blank">
<img src="lol.jpg"/>
</a>
```

The idea is to make images open in a new page to view the full size image, and I'm adding a class in case I want to make it into a popup later on.
I'm looking to do this in PHP, can someone please help me?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a database of these images or only an html file?  If all you have is an html file you will have to write a program to parse that file and make a new one with the desired output

Comment: Try something first, ask if you encounter problems....

Comment: Look at jquery. It can do this easily and without loading a new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He asked for solution in PHP (see tags).

```
$string = <<<EOD
<img src="lol.jpg">
<img src="lol.jpg"/>
<img src="lol.jpg" alt="sufix"/>
<img alt="prefix" src="lol.jpg"/>
EOD;

$pattern = '/<img[^>]+src="([a-z.]+)"[^>]*>/i';
$replacement = '<a href="${1}">${0}</a>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

**Online version**: http://ideone.com/pY2EWY

Comment: Small note: your example does not work for images that have a full url instead of just an image. If you use for example http://www.google.com/lol.jpg it won't work.

Comment: @xtrimsky While your attempted edit makes sense, it's generally best to not to perform an edit that actually changes the answer. Your comment is the best way to suggest an actual change.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just use some jquery, try this :

```
<script>
        $(function(){
                $('.thisimg').replace('<a href="your location" class="your class" target="_blank"><img src="your src" class="thisimg" /></a>');
        });
</script>

<img src="your src" class="thisimg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing so... Most involving Javascript.

Take a look at jquery's method `wrap()`, that wraps any selected element into another element:

```
$("img").each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    $(this).wrap("<a href='"+href+"' class='image_inside_text' target='_blank'></a>");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('img').each(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr("src");
        $( this ).replaceWith('<a href="' + src +'" class="image_inside_text" target="_blank"><img src="' + src + '"/></a>')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use output buffering: [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and do something similar to this example and replacing the callback with what [test30](https://stackoverflow.com/users/781312/test30) suggested:

```
<?php

function callback($buffer)
{
  // replace all the apples with oranges
  return (str_replace("apples", "oranges", $buffer));
}

ob_start("callback");

?>
<html>
<body>
<p>It's like comparing apples to oranges.</p>
</body>
</html>
<?php

ob_end_flush();

?>
```